# error: ReactNative error ENOENT:no such file or directory, uv_cwd(null

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Any suggestions to fix error below?

```
Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error ENOENT:no such file or directory, uv_cwd(null)
```

I tried this, but that did not work:

- react-native upgrade `react-native upgrade`
- unlink and link the module
- uninstalling the package and reinstalling

I am on iOS emulator and here are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^3.7.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.42.3",
    "react-native-material-kit": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Comment: it is a new app or are you trying to integrate with existing app?

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to integrate existing app. Dependencies of existing app is old and i can not run. so i updated dependencies with latest version.

Comment: did you try this here ? http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps

Comment: Oh react-native update could be a little complicated and you can present errors when updating the dependencies. many times react-native link doesnt help. so you have to link manually all the libraries that your app uses. make sure that all the libs are linked in xcode. if not try to post the project on github. so 
I can download it and maybe help you. I'm sure it is a problem of compatibility.

Comment: Thank you :D  While i was trying workaround, it's fixed. I guess code below worked:
`react-native bundle --dev false --platform ios --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios` AND/OR 
`react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle`

Answer (score 0):

When components and packages update, they make changes to their components and how they work. Some are application breaking, however if you are updating from old (6+ months) packages you might have to change a lot of your code according to the docs for those packages. It's always better to keep up to date with depencies instead of doing it every other month.

Answer (score 0):

put this on terminal

```
$ killall node
```

and check it again